# Video and Audio not match on UDP stream Playing in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, stream, udp, android-videoview

I develop a video player for UDP stream in Android with Android studio (help from this [LINK](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888)).

I generate this stream from dvb-t source and stream format is MPEG-2/TS as this [this doc](http://www.videolan.org/projects/dvblast.html).

The UDP stream play successful but the Audio of Video not match with video. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is it matches on source? do you send data in video format (audio and video) in the same package or separately?

Comment: edit question and add video format...video stream and sound stream together

Answer (score 1):

Did you ensure the sync frame is present in your source UDP stream? 
https://wiki.videolan.org/VSG:Audio:Out_of_Sync/

Does your player read the sync frame to ensure proper alignment?

If you are not sure, you can take a working Android, open source UDP MPEG-2/TS player (e.g. https://github.com/VideoExpertsGroup/MediaPlayerSDK) and use it to both troubleshoot your source stream and the solve the problem by seeing how the sync frame is used.

Comment: About [link](https://wiki.videolan.org/VSG:Audio:Out_of_Sync/), notify you that I do not use VLC, I used VideoView. About ques 2 : Really I dont know that , I open the VideoView with initial the multicast stream URL, on Android studio I didnt see any error about playing video on debug mode. I can try your player suggestion or VLC but I want use VideoView as much as possible.